# What is the best way to simulate human body wounds in Blender?

Tags: modeling

with Blender, we are trying to emulate crime scene with human figure. While we can get the figure quite easily (from MakeHuman program), it becomes difficult to simulate wounds on human body. Any help, please ?

Comment: What sort of wounds? Deep, showing bone? For animation or illustration?

Comment: Hi, shallow, just for illustration. We are beginers :)

Comment: Then the I would suggest making a new UV unwrapping and then painting the wounds directly on to the model. In cycles node you can select which UV is used and mix them together. So you can have one for the main "skin" another for wounds and another for clothes. Google "Blender texture painting" to get started.